# How to unpack netCDF CMIP5 Climate data to a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I’m new to the .nc file format and have looked extensively through available answers – if I’ve missed something, any help is appreciated!

I have a CMIP5 climate file (netCDF4 format) – the dimensions are daily values over ten years for: latitude, longitude, temperature, climate projection, time. I need to iterate through each location (lat/lon pair) for each projection and perform operations on the temperature data for each month or year by location (for example, I want to sum the temperature value for all days in a single year in a single location).

Using ncdump, the following data is available:

[image]

Currently, I am trying to write the file to an intermediate form as an array or dataframe in Python. Is there a simple way to unpack the netCDF data and write to an array? The ideal output format would be along the lines of a dataframe where each row is a single entry with the following column headers: “latitude”, “longitude”, “projection”, “temperature”, “time”. I’ve seen examples for 2D or 3D arrays, but can’t seem to work for the higher dimensional data.

Time/memory is less important than having an intermediate data format to check the calculations against.

Code:

```
import netCDF4
import collections
from collections import defaultdict

t1 = netCDF4.MFDataset("Extraction_tasmax.nc") #
t1.variables.keys()
tmax = t1.variables['tasmax']


lat = t1.variables['latitude'][:]    
lon = t1.variables['longitude'][:]
time = t1.variables['time'][:]
tempmax = t1.variables['tasmax'][:, :, :, :] # projection, time, lat, lon
column_names = ['tempmax', 'projection', 'time', 'latitude', 'longitude']
temp_list = []
            

for projection in tempmax:
    for time in projection:
        for lat in time:
            for lon in lat:
                temp_list.append([tempmax, projection, time, lat, lon])


temperature_data = pd.DataFrame(temp_list, columns = column_names)
```

EDIT: Current output (small clip - returning very large data list)

[image]

Comment: can you add the code of what you've tried?

Comment: hi @Yuca - code has been added above

Comment: can you include the output of your code?

Comment: The current output ('temp_list') is > 1.8 million entries (a single value for each of the variables). Is there an easy way to post that here? The place I'm stuck: is it possible iterate through a .nc file (netCDF4 format) and save each iteration in a list, dictionary, or other human-readable file type?

Comment: the output can be just the first 5 rows, to give an idea of the structure you have vs the structure you want

Comment: added at end of post. Thanks

Comment: your output seems like the contents of the list, what about temperature_data, can you do temperature_data.head(5)?

Answer (score 0):

Very much late to the party here, but in case anyone else stumbles upon this question...

This can be done very easily with [xarray](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/getting-started-guide/why-xarray.html). xarray got it's start working with netCDF climate data just like this, and has evolved into a powerful pydata-core library.

You can load the data with [`xr.open_dataset`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_dataset.html):

```py
ds = xr.open_dataset("Extraction_tasmax.nc")
```

And the data can be converted into a DataFrame with the [`xr.Dataset.to_dataframe`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.to_dataframe.html) method:

```py
df = ds.to_dataframe()
```

Note that this will broadcast all non-dimansion coordinates and data_variables against one another. That seems like it's what you want, but in case it isn't, you can do this with one variable at a time to get a dictionary of variables:

```py
output_dataframes = {}

for v in ds.data_variables:
    output_dataframes[v] = ds[[v]].to_dataframe()
```